# Are there Islamic guidelines on how and when to protest?

Tags: quran, sharia, hadith, sunnah, shiism

Are there any guidelines provided by Islam on **how** and **when** to protest?

And **how** to decide the **magnitude** of protests and **who** will decide it?

Please cite references from the Holy Quran, Ahadeth, Islamic history, and the life of Prophet Muhammad(PBUH) or Ahleybayt.

Comment: No need to shout. Please avoid all caps unless necessary.

Comment: Are you asking about political protests, economic boycotts, or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by protest? Do you mean Qyam (قیام) ?

Comment: have a look at question here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17048/importance-of-protest-in-islam?lq=1

Comment: little bit related... [What is standard Islam practice regarding religious authority figures?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7432/what-is-standard-islam-practice-regarding-religious-authority-figures)

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience in this having done a protest myself. The prophet (pbuh) did a protest once, where he cut down palm trees. This is in the Quran and the noted down in the life of the prophet.

What you O Muslims cut down of a palm tree of the enemy or you left it standing on its stem it was by the Leave of Allah, and in order that He might disgrace the Fasiqun (59:5).

It is narrated on the authority of 'Abdullah that the Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him) ordered the date-palms of Banu Nadir to be burnt and cut. These palms were at Buwaira. Qutaibah and Ibn Rumh in their versions of the tradition have added: So Allah, the Glorious and Exalted, revealed the verse:" Whatever trees you have cut down or left standing on their trunks, it was with the permission of Allah so that He may disgrace the evil-doers" Sahih Muslim 19:4326

The Quran explains that in law there is a balance. This means that although the prophet (pbuh) was cutting down the trees, he was doing it to counteract his enemies oppressing the Muslims. This balance is mentioned in the Quran:

We verily sent Our messengers with clear proofs, and revealed with them the Scripture and the Balance, that mankind may observe right measure; and He revealed iron, wherein is mighty power and (many) uses for mankind, and that Allah may know him who helpeth Him and His messengers, though unseen. Lo! Allah is Strong, Almighty. (57:25)

As for the sky, He raised it ˹high˺, and set the balance ˹of justice˺ (55:7)
That you be not defiant in the Balance. (55:8)
So establish weight with justice and fall not short in the balance.(55:9)

You would be surprised that this is also English law. When I stood in court and explained to them what I was doing, the Judge had to explain to Jury the balance of justice, as most people don't know about it. He said that you are allowed to break the law in a lesser way to counteract others breaking the law against you.

If you are doing a protest like this, the magnitude of your protest will depend on what extent people are breaking the law against you. For example I was breaking a restraining order that was put around my university, and breaking university Guidlines by sticking up posters. Your case might be different.

The decision of a protest can be made by you, you don't need to go to anyone. I would encourage you to protects against injustice, as this is righteous but at the same time tell you to refrain from rebellion.

Allah commands justice, the doing of good, and liberality to kith and kin, and He forbids all shameful deeds, and injustice and rebellion: He instructs you, that ye may receive admonition.(16:90)

Answer (score 0):

`Sorry for bad english.`

---

How ??

the mosaad answer

---

Is ther is guidelines??

yes;

- You should be sure that this act is "HARAM" or hateful.
- there is no other accepted advisory opinion saying that this act is halal.
- You should be able to do the protests.
- You should be able to bear the harm `if present` caused by the protests
- The harm of the protests shouldn't be expected to affect other people who can't bear it.

"لا يكلف الله نفسا الا وسعها"

"God does not ask someone to do what he can't bear"

---

Notes:

The net result of the evil in `fault plus the protests process` should never be more than the evil introduced by the fault itself.

ie: Don't try to remove fault by another fault greater than it, or by process which will cause another fault greater than original one.

"والله لا يحب الفساد"

"God does not love evil"

what is the relation between the last aya and the conditions ?

N.B:Allah hates the first evil; and ask you to remove it.
N.B:the evil introduced by the protests process is an evil; Allah hates it.

`So you are subjected to decrease the totel evil to the minimum possible level`

---

who ??

- all muslims are subjected to do protest by thier hearts in all conditions
- other kinds of protest needs the conditions to be fullfilled.
- The leader of any groub of people `should` use his Authority to fullfill good things in his groub. 
  "That leader may be father, mother or manager "
  "كلكم راع وكلكم مسئول عن رعيته"
  "You is a shepherd and each of you is responsible for his flock."

---

Who decide the magnitude??

according to the conditions, what the act?? where is it ?? who do it ?? What is the expected eation ?? Is there is a harm ?? who wil be affected ??

examples: 
In your home           >>  you can decide;
In personal occasions  >>  you can decide or consult some one.
In general  events     >>  muslims should make meeting to decide.

http://www.jameataleman.org/main/articles.aspx?article_no=2241

Answer (score -1):

If there is something which runs contrary to the teachings of the prophet (pbuh) then it is the duty of ALL muslims to protest. This could be a woman refusing to dress appropriately, someone refusing to fulfill their duty as a muslim or a non-believer attacking the honor of all muslims.

> وَاقْتُلُوهُمْ حَيْثُ ثَقِفْتُمُوهُمْ وَأَخْرِجُوهُم مِّنْ حَيْثُ أَخْرَجُوكُمْ وَالْفِتْنَةُ أَشَدُّ مِنَ الْقَتْلِ وَلاَ تُقَاتِلُوهُمْ عِندَ الْمَسْجِدِ الْحَرَامِ حَتَّى يُقَاتِلُوكُمْ فِيهِ فَإِن قَاتَلُوكُمْ فَاقْتُلُوهُمْ كَذَلِكَ جَزَاء الْكَافِرِينَ

You may kill those who wage war against you, and you may evict them whence they evicted you. Oppression is worse than murder. Do not fight them at the Sacred Masjid, unless they attack you therein. If they attack you, you may kill them. This is the just retribution for those disbelievers. (Al-Baqra:191)

Comment: (p.s. I'm sunni)

Comment: The second paragraph does not seem in-place with the rest of this answer (or the question); that seems an unrelated subject. Or are you saying that "protest" and "open murder" are interchangeable concepts?

Comment: we as muslims have duty to give advice only it is not our duty to punish people because of their chosen way of life thats why judgment day is there for where every one will be judged on their sins not human to another

Comment: you are trying to use quranic versus to your advantage mention the two versus before this one and the two after it to clarify the meaning for the verse u mention, does one suppose go around shooting nonbeliever wherever found, Islam is the fastest growing religion is this what every one is suppose to do and shed blood Islam is not violent you are trying to make it so, and i do understand the meaning of these versus clearly differently than you do