# Is it a sin to protest against your leader? What is the proper way to protest?

Tags: halal-haram, behavior, politics

I have seen this [**question**](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2763/protests-in-islam) but it is not answered

**Is it a sin to protest against your leader?**

Because the leader is the one who is selected by Allah on nation and people have to follow him. 
There is way if we have to change a brutal leader we have to change ourself.

**As in Quran:**

> "Verily, God does not change the state of a People until they change themselves."(Quran 13:11)

**But what is the proper way to protest?** Should we take matters in or hand our let Allah handle it and be a good Muslim by ourself.

Comment: Are you implying that Allah selects even tyrants to rule over the people? How consistent is that with Allah's benevolence and mercy?

Comment: @Hamza I dont think you understand Quran(2:30) correctly. It is talking about when god created Adam and told the angels that humans will have authority over other creatures on earth.

Comment: @infatuated sorry my question got off topic now I have edited it.

Comment: @mosaad sorry now i have update my question see it.

Comment: You have answered your own question in the question body! Our fight and struggle against tyranny is part of Allah's will. In other words, Allah deposes tyrants through our will!

Comment: @infatuated okay but how to protest against tyrants? If we will take guns it will weak our country like in Libya and Egypt. does Islam have answer to this.

Comment: little bit related... [What is standard Islam practice regarding religious authority figures?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7432/what-is-standard-islam-practice-regarding-religious-authority-figures)

Answer (score 1):

there is very specific condition about it. not Every leader is chosen by Allah. so if you talk about only islam, being in domain in islam,then the leader means Khalifah, and if he is legitimate and made khalifah by proper rules of islam (not Fake khalifah).

Considering above conditions, even if that leader tries to oppress you,then you cannot revolt,you cannot attack back, ONLY and Only if he goes against shariah. If he goes against rules of islam, anywhere in ruling according to Quran and Sunnah, then you have 100% freedom to stop him by all possible means. (ofcourse start step by step, dont just go and kill him).

and regarding how to protest,you have to follow the sunnah way of protesting to stop him from something, if he goes against sunnah and Quran and rulings. you should try to talk to him, if he does not agree, then try to get enough force or consult the Shura to take him down as khalifa and chose another one. as a person,who continue to go against Quran and sunnah, cannot remain a leader of muslim ummah at all

Comment: What if the nation is not islamic, the leader of non islamic country is a tyrant say, then what?